# How does this form gets the label name of each input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-request

I'm working on some else project which is a Laravel 9 project and I have seen something interesting that have not seen it before.

Basically he defined the form inputs of projects like this (example):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <span class="text-danger">*</span>
    <label>{{ __('news')['nws_title'] }}</label>
    <input type="text" name="nws_title" value="{{ old('nws_title' ,!empty($new) ? $new->nws_title : '') }}">
</div>
```

So as you can see for the `<label>`, this has been added:

`{{ __('news')['nws_title'] }}`

But I don't know what on earth is  `__('news')` and what type of variable is this and how it calls the `nws_title` local name as label !!

So if you know, please let me know...

Also in the blade, he called the form request as well:

```
@php 
$validationRequest = new \App\Http\Requests\News\NewsRequest();
$is_star = $validationRequest->rules();
@endphp
```

And this is the `NewsRequest`:

```
public function rules()
    {
        if($this->method() == 'POST') {
            return [
                'nws_title' => ['required'],
                'nws_cat_id' => ['required'],
                'nws_publish' => ['required', 'digits_between:0,1'],
                'nws_lead' => ['required_if:nws_publish,1'],
                'nws_description' => ['required_if:nws_publish,1'],
                'nws_feature_image' => ['nullable', 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,bmp' ],
                'nws_thumbnail_image' => ['nullable', 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,bmp', 'dimensions:min_width=200,min_height=200,ratio=1/1' ],
                'gallery.*' => ['mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,bmp', 'nullable'],
            ];
        }

        return [
            'nws_title' => ['required'],
            'nws_cat_id' => ['required'],
            'nws_publish' => ['required'],
            'nws_lead' => ['required_if:nws_publish,1'],
            'nws_description' => ['required_if:nws_publish,1'],
            'nws_feature_image' => ['nullable', 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,bmp'],
            'nws_thumbnail_image' => ['nullable', 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,bmp', 'dimensions:min_width=200,min_height=200,ratio=1/1'],
            'gallery.*' => ['mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,bmp', 'nullable'],
        ];
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`__()` is [a helper method for translation/localization](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-__). Depends on how localization is implemented in the app, but if it follows Laravel's default localization feature, then you can consult to the doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/localization).